# Is there a guide to setting up Mozilla Thunderbird to use my GPG keys to sign and/or encrypt email messages on Windows?

Tags: email, encryption, gnupg, digital-signature, gpg4win

I see instructions on websites and questions here about using GPG keys with Thunderbird in Linux, but nothing on Windows. I have GPG, Kleopatra, and Thunderbird 3 installed on Windows, I made my GPG key, and now, I'm ready to have Thunderbird start using it for signing and encrypting emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in using GPG with thunderbird, you may find Enigmail simpler to set up than gpg4win:

http://enigmail.mozdev.org/documentation/quickstart.php

Comment: I have GPG4Win already set up. I'm familiar with how it works and how to use it. However, it looks like this Enigmail with gpg4win and Kleopatra, side by side. I'm still looking into it, though.

Comment: I installed Enigmail on my Windows install of Thunderbird and during configuration, it did detect that I was using gpg4win and used that key store. It appears to be working.

Answer (score 0):

It's built into Thunderbird 3.1

See [Setting Up Email Encryption and Signing with Mozilla Thunderbird 3.1](http://www.unibia.com/unibianet/systems-networking/setting-email-encryption-and-signing-mozilla-thunderbird-31).